# Linking to Dynamic Content in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, hyperlink

I have three models.  User, Product, and Season.

I used a standard "has many through" approach:

user `has_many :seasons`
user has_many :products, :through => :seasons

product `has_many :seasons`
product has_many :users, :through => :seasons

seasons `belong_to :product`
seasons `belong_to :user`

On my "show" view for my users, I display the user's products.  I do this as follows:

```
    <% @user.seasons.each do |c| %>
      <%=h c.product.name %>
    <% end %>
```

This all works great.

Here's my question.  How do I create a hyperlink to the show view of whatever product is generated by this code <%=h c.product.name %>?  I followed the API and tried using a block, but none of my attempts worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <% @user.seasons.each do |c| %>
    <%= link_to c.product.name, c.product %>
  <% end %>
```